# Procedimiento almacenado de MySQL a Oracle, falta INTO

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedure

Estoy intentando programar en Oracle este procedimiento almacenado de MySQL, pero me da errores:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nombres_a()
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM cliente
      WHERE nombre LIKE 'a%';   
  END;
```

He intentado ésto, pero me pide que utilice `INTO`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nombres_a IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM cliente
      WHERE nombre LIKE 'a%';   
  END;
```

¿Hay forma que de Oracle muestre el resultado de un `SELECT` desde un procedimiento almacenado tal y como sí permite MySQL?

Comment: Busque en el blog de Don Burleson, el hombre esta durísimo en Oracle

Comment: El problema es que no está diciendo aquí qué hacer con ese select. No es obvio que esto deba ir a la salida estándar (consola) o a alguna otra parte. Como sugerencia, en las preguntas se incluye el mensaje de error completo.